# I'm trying to get the gclid (from google ads) from the query string using Next.js but the value never shows up

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, google-ads-api

I'm using Next.js on my application and I'm trying to get the gclid (google click id) from the query string and store it on localStorage using this hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
// Access the gclid parameter from the URL
const gclidParam = router.query.gclid;

if (Array.isArray(gclidParam)) {
  // If gclidParam is an array, take the first element
  const gclid = gclidParam[0];
  localStorage.setItem('gclid', gclid);
} else if (typeof gclidParam === 'string') {
  // If gclidParam is a string, directly use it
  localStorage.setItem('gclid', gclidParam);
}
console.log(localStorage)
  }, [router.query.gclid]);
```

But, for some reason, it never shows up. Can someone help me?

Comment: It can be related to Safari in iOS 17 and macOS Sonoma removing gclid parameters from URLs as part of their advanced tracking and fingerprint protection.